# Share dimensions between widgets

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter we can use `Themes` to share colors and font styles.
https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Is there an existing best practice that we can use in a similar manner share values such as margins, paddings and widths or heights?

Preferably something that helps stick to the material design guidelines.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking. What do you want exactly?

Comment: @RémiRousselet In a container we can do the following to set the color:

`Container(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor);`


In a similar way I was wondering if there is an existing approach that would allow me for example to do the following:

`EdgeInsets.all(SomeMaterialDimensions.of(context).cardMargin);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Defining custom widgets**

The easiest and probably most elegant approach is to define custom widgets, like a `MyRaisedButton` that internally uses the `RaisedButton` with the right dimensions.

```
class MyRaisedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  MyRaisedButton({
    this.child,
    this.onPressed,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      padding: ...,
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: child
    );
  }
}
```

This works surprisingly well in most cases.
However, if you still want to keep your widgets flexible (being able to pass a lot of customization options to the constructor), your overall widget definition quickly gets very long, because you need to forward all the options to the `RaisedButton`.
In that case, it makes sense to actually share the values throughout the app.

**Actually sharing values throughout the app**

Of course, this approach is possible too.
Due to Flutter's openness, we can just look at [how the `Theme` is implemented](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart) and copy that code to create a custom widget that functions just like a `Theme`.
Here's a boiled-down version:

```
@immutable
class MyThemeData {
  MyThemeData({
    this.myPadding,
    this.myColor,
    this.myString
  });

  final Padding myPadding;
  final Color myColor;
  final String myString;
}

class MyTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  MyTheme({
    Key key,
    @required this.data,
    @required this.child
  }) : super(key: key);

  final MyThemeData data;
  final Widget child;

  static MyThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(MyTheme) as MyTheme)?.data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => child;
}
```

Now, you can just wrap the `MaterialApp` in a `MyTheme` widget:

```
MyTheme(
  data: MyThemeData(
    myPadding: ...,
    myColor: ...,
    ...
  ),
  child: ... (here goes the MaterialApp)
)
```

Then anywhere in your app, you can write `MyTheme.of(context).myPadding`.
You can adapt the `MyThemeData` class to your needs, storing anything you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marcel. For me the second approach seems more elegant as I can share values between different types of widgets. 

I think though that it will be better if the final solution is a combination of the two options together