# What's a good way of defining theme objects in Flutter(Dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know about the theme object "ThemeData" and i'm making use of that as well, but alas the need for extending it has arisen.

What I'm trying to accomplish is defining style sets to reference throughout my app. For example i have this

```dart
child: Text(
  advisoryServiceStatus[item.status - 1],
  style: TextStyle(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
),
```

and i want to move the TextStyle in a file so i can do something like

```dart
child: Text(
  advisoryServiceStatus[item.status - 1],
  style: extendedThemeConfig.textStyles.mutedText,
```

but i have troubled properly defining my style object. Here's what i tried. Maybe i shouldn't be using classes, but i haven't managed to define them as objects. (my understanding of the concepts is a bit shabby)

This is how i tried to define my extendedThemeConfig

```dart
class TextStyles {
  final TextStyle mutedText = TextStyle(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);
}

class ExtendedThemeConfig {
  TextStyles textStyles;
}

const extendedThemeConfig = ExtendedThemeConfig;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your approach doesn't work**

It probably does work, but features like hot-reload aren't supported, because you introduce global state to your app, which is often not what you want.

**So, how to do it better?**

I already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072372/share-dimensions-between-widgets/54077940#54077940) more elaborately, but here's a version adapted to your problem:

Because Flutter is open source, we can just look at [how the `Theme` is implemented](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart) and copy that code to create a custom widget that functions just like a `Theme`.
Here's a boiled-down version:

```dart
@immutable
class MyThemeData {
  MyThemeData({
    this.mutedText,
  });

  final TextStyle mutedText;
}

class MyTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  MyTheme({
    Key key,
    @required this.data,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final MyThemeData data;
  final Widget child;

  static MyThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(MyTheme) as MyTheme)?.data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => child;
}
```

Now, you can just wrap the `MaterialApp` in a `MyTheme` widget:

```dart
MyTheme(
  data: MyThemeData(
    mutedText: ...,
  ),
  child: ... (here goes the MaterialApp)
)
```

Then anywhere in your app, you can write `MyTheme.of(context).mutedText`.
You can adapt the `MyThemeData` class to your needs, storing anything you want.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "copy that code to create a custom widget that functions just like a Theme". The code you posted and the code of theme look vastly different, i'm confused.
Of course it would be ideal to just have an actual theme object to which i can just add my properties, but why are there no fields that show up in the basic theme configuration showing in the code of the theme object??? I am very confused

Comment: You're right "copy that code" might be badly phrased. This is a very boiled-down version of the `Theme`, but it functions just like it, especially if you compare the `of` method.
This is how it works: Basically, you have a `ThemeData` class which holds all the properties and a `Theme` class, which is a widget that makes the `ThemeData` accessible in the subtree that's wrapped inside it. So `Theme.of(context)` actually gives you a `ThemeData` object that contains the properties.

Comment: I copied the code you wrote as it is to test it but it doesn't work. It doesn't let me reference "MyTheme". Will the confusion ever stop? :(

Comment: Hmm too bad. What's the error that's showing? Did you import the file where you defined the `MyTheme`?

Comment: I just put the code in my main.dart file where MaterialApp is. Then i tried to use in another file(a widget), assuming it would be available since it wraps the app basically. This is how i tried ot use it `style: MyTheme.of(context).mutedText`

Comment: That's a static compilation error and has nothing to do with the actual code being faulty. You should be able to just `import 'main.dart';` in the other file. (The widget tree has nothing to do with the available namespaces in your dart files.)